# regarding the ntile function in pyspark windows function

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running the following code segment,

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import ntile
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

simpleData = (("James", "Sales", 3000), \
    ("Michael", "Sales", 4600),  \
    ("Robert", "Sales", 4100),   \
    ("Maria", "Finance", 3000),  \
    ("James", "Sales", 3000),    \
    ("Scott", "Finance", 3300),  \
    ("Jen", "Finance", 3900),    \
    ("Jeff", "Marketing", 3000), \
    ("Kumar", "Marketing", 2000),\
    ("Saif", "Sales", 4100) \
  )
 
columns= ["employee_name", "department", "salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)windowSpec  = 
Window.partitionBy("department").orderBy("salary")
df.withColumn("ntile",ntile(2).over(windowSpec)).show()
```

The result is shown as follows, and I am confused on how does ntile(2) works, why the first and second rows get nitle column value as `1`, and why the third row and fourth row get `1` and `2` respectively even though they have the same salary value. I just cannot figure out how does this ntile columns calculated?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ntile window function is used to break the result set into a ***specified number of approximately equal groups, or buckets***. The ntile function returns the bucket number associated with each row. The ntile name is derived from the practice of dividing result sets into fourths (quartile), tenths (decile), and so on.

If the number of rows is not divisible by buckets, the ntile function results in groups of two sizes with the difference by one. ***The larger groups always come before the smaller group in the order specified in the ORDER BY clause.***

The example you have provided breaks the employees in each department into two groups:

```
Window.partitionBy("department").orderBy("salary")
df.withColumn("ntile",ntile(2).over(windowSpec)).show()
```

- First, the partitionBy divided the employees by department names into partitions.
- Then, the orderBy sorted the employees in each partition by salary.
- Finally, the ntile(2) function assigned each row in each partition a bucket number. It reset the bucket number whenever the department changes.

Now I have introduced one additional employee `MariaZ` that would be helpful to understand better.

```
simpleData = (("James", "Sales", 3000), \
    ("Michael", "Sales", 4600),  \
    ("Robert", "Sales", 4100),   \
    ("Maria", "Finance", 3000),  \
    ("MariaZ", "Sales", 3000),  \
    ("James", "Sales", 3000),    \
    ("Scott", "Finance", 3300),  \
    ("Jen", "Finance", 3900),    \
    ("Jeff", "Marketing", 3000), \
    ("Kumar", "Marketing", 2000),\
    ("Saif", "Sales", 4100) \
  )
 
columns= ["employee_name", "department", "salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("department").orderBy("salary")
df.withColumn("ntile",ntile(2).over(windowSpec)).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
|employee_name|department|salary|ntile|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
|        James|     Sales|  3000|    1|
|       MariaZ|     Sales|  3000|    1|
|        James|     Sales|  3000|    1|
|       Robert|     Sales|  4100|    2|
|         Saif|     Sales|  4100|    2|
|      Michael|     Sales|  4600|    2|
|        Maria|   Finance|  3000|    1|
|        Scott|   Finance|  3300|    1|
|          Jen|   Finance|  3900|    2|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  2000|    1|
|         Jeff| Marketing|  3000|    2|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

`ntile()` is defined by SQL to return tiles that are as equal in size as possible.  This results in exactly what you see -- ties can be split (arbitrarily) across different rows.

Instead of `ntile()`, you can use a direct calculation.  Here is one method:

```
ceil(rank() over (partition by department order by salary) * 2.0 /
     count(*) over (partition by department)
    )
```

Note that the tiles are not necessarily the same size -- and some tiles could be missing entirely.  However, ties are all put into the same tile.